# Pig: Multiple UDF in one class

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, udf

I want to define multiple Pig UDF. Each of them will extract a different part of the data. In my case the data are JSON documents that have a complex structure including many nested JSON objects.

The problem is that for now I have created a different Eval class for every function that I need. Each of these classes implements the exec().
Is there a way to put all the functions to the same UDF class and call them from pig?

Example of one of my UDF:

```
public class PigGetTimestamps extends EvalFunc<Tuple>{
  public Tuple exec(org.apache.pig.data.Tuple input) throws IOException {        

    if (input == null || input.size() == 0 ){
        return null;
    }

    try {

        String inputString = DataType.toString(input.get(0));
        try
        {
            String[] tokens=inputString.split("\t");
            if (tokens.length<1)
                return null;
            Document document=new Document(tokens[0], true, false);
            long timestamp_fetch=document.getTimestamp_fetch();
            long timestamp_pub=document.getTimestampPub();
            Tuple output = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(2);
            output.set(0,timestamp_pub);
            output.set(1,timestamp_fetch);
            return output;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {   
        System.out.println("Can't extract field; error = " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same class, create several instances of it - when in the constructor you will state what function will it do

So in your pig you will define the different instances:

```
define udf1 my.package.udf.MultiFunc('1');
define udf2 my.package.udf.MultiFunc('2');
```

And you UDF class will look like :

```
    public class MultiFunc  extends EvalFunc<String> {

        private String operation;
        public MultiFunc(String operation){
            this.data = operation;

        }

        @Override
        public String exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {
        switch (operation){
            case "+":
                //your code here;
                break;

            case "-":
                //your code here;
                break;

            break;

        }        
}
```

Comment: Is there any standard way, you might get the result but it is a hack